# Generate a typolink with nav_title instead of title as link text

Tags: typo3, fluid, typolink

How can I configure TYPO3 7.6 / 8.7 to use nav_title instead/before title on generating page links with fluid_styled_content?

Currently I'm using

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="7"></f:link.typolink>
```

in my fluid template. (https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Link/TypolinkViewHelper.html)

This generates me a translated page link using the page.title field.
I need to output the page.nav_title field there.

With css_styled_content (instead of fluid_styled_content) I could access/output the value in TS like

```
temp.field_title = TEXT
temp.field_title.value = nav_title // title
```

(This was working similar in HMENU / TMENU ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intended behavior of the typolink function. The Fluid `typolink` viewhelper uses [stdWrap](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#typolink) to generate the link for a given content. If you do not provide any content to be "typolinked", then the typolink will always render the title of a given page uid as a fallback.

Pure TypoScript example with no content:

```
temp.field_title = TEXT
temp.field_title.typolink.parameter = 7
```

This example will render the page title of page uid 7, since no content for the `TEXT` is given.

In order to render the nav_title as content of the typolink viewhelper, I suggest to use the `page.info` viewhelper from the [vhs](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/vhs) extension.

Example:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
<f:link.typolink parameter="7">
    <v:page.info pageUid="7" field="nav_title"/>
</f:link.typolink>
```